# Laravel get all groups along with the count of each groups group members using join query

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5.4

I have two tables 'Group'('id', 'title', 'description') and 'Group_members'('id', 'group_id', 'user_id'). When ever a user joins a group, a row is created in 'group_members' table.

What I need is to fetch all groups along with the number of members in each group,
something like:-

```
[
    {
        id: 1
        title: group1
        description: lorem ipsum
        member_count: 5
    }{
        id: 2
        title: group2
        description: lorem ipsum
        member_count: 7
    }
]
```

What I have done so far is,

```
    DB::table('group')
        ->join('group_members', 
        function($join){
            $join->on('group_members.group_id', '=', 'group.id')
            ->distinct()->pluck('group_members.user_id')->count();
        })
        ->get();
```

which returns error

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on `group`.`id` = `group_members`.`group_id

Please Help

Comment: Can to show the generated SQL string ?

Comment: (SQL: select distinct `group_members`.`user_id` on `group_members`.`group_id` = `group`.`id`)

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on `group_members`.`group_id` = `group`.`id`' at line 1 (SQL: select distinct `group_members`.`user_id` on `group_members`.`group_id` = `group`.`id`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got your relationship set up in your Group model like

```
public function group_members()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\GroupMember');
}
```

and in GroupMember model like

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}
```

you should be able to do

```
$groups = Group::all();

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $group->member_count = $group->group_members()->count();
}

$groupsArray = $groups->toArray();
```

Or

```
$group = Group::where('column', 'value')->with('group_members')->first();
$count = $group->group_members->count();
```

**Read up on [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) and [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections) in the docs**

---

You could also use a mutatus/accessor to return the member count as a property of the model so in your Group model

```
getGroupMemberCountAttribute() {
    return $this->group_members()->count();
}
```

And use it like

```
$group->group_member_count;
```

Comment: Thank you.Tried this one but this wonn't return the right syntax in which I needed.

Comment: How do you need the syntax and why? It's much simpler to use relationships and collections for this. You may just need to manipulate the collection slightly if you absolutely have to have the count as a property of the array.

Comment: Sorry it is for an API endpoint, so need the syntax as I described above.

Comment: I didn't get what 'members' represents here. Could you please tell me what it is?

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to return the data as you want it. Instead of echoing out you just had to add it to the object. It's simple stuff and Laravel has built in functionality for all this.

Comment: `$groups = Group::all();

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $group->member_count = $group->group_members()->count();
}

$groupsArray = $groups->toArray();`